# Can two or more people works at one project using vb.net(server side)

Tags: sql, vb.net

We are creating a new project. Me and my friends are going to create one file. Using vb.net and sql server is that possible that we can edit the project at the same time?(like web base but server side)

Comment: You need to look into source control.

Comment: is visualsvn a source control that can be used by another user?

Comment: MS DevOps which wraps Git is build in to Visual Studio. don't need to have it any more complicated.  There is a cloud copy of you project, In effect you would each have a local version to work on that gets synced with the cloud version

Comment: just use GutHub, is free. But try to avoid single file work and organize your work and code. Some architecture is needed.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops/

Comment: If you use VisualSVN as your source control provider, you'll need an SVN server somewhere. Not sure that public servers are available. It's probably better to use a service where public servers are already available in the cloud, like DevOps, GitHub or GitLab.